# Building Conda package from scratch (tutorial) fails on tests / package layout

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I'm following https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tutorials/build-pkgs.html to build my first (private) Python package. I do not have it hosted on PyPi, nor I would like to. I figured out that the problem I'm running into is the same as with the demo at the linked tutorial. I.e., I follow the steps, create the `meta.yaml` and `build.bat` (skipping the `.sh` as Im Windows only), move into the directory with Anaconda prompt, and run `conda-build .`. The error message is the following:

```
(base) C:\Users\jvanzundert\conda-bld\pyinstrument_1535453523573\test_tmp>call "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat" "C:\Users\jvanzundert\conda-bld\pyinstrument_1535453523573\_test_env"

(C:\Users\jvanzundert\conda-bld\pyinstrument_1535453523573\_test_env) C:\Users\jvanzundert\conda-bld\pyinstrument_1535453523573\test_tmp>IF 0 NEQ 0 exit 1

(C:\Users\jvanzundert\conda-bld\pyinstrument_1535453523573\_test_env) C:\Users\jvanzundert\conda-bld\pyinstrument_1535453523573\test_tmp>"C:\Users\jvanzundert\conda-bld\pyinstrument_1535453523573\_test_env\python.exe" -s "C:\Users\jvanzundert\conda-bld\pyinstrument_1535453523573\test_tmp\run_test.py"
import: 'pyinstrument'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jvanzundert\conda-bld\pyinstrument_1535453523573\test_tmp\run_test.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pyinstrument
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyinstrument'

(C:\Users\jvanzundert\conda-bld\pyinstrument_1535453523573\_test_env) C:\Users\jvanzundert\conda-bld\pyinstrument_1535453523573\test_tmp>IF 1 NEQ 0 exit 1
Tests failed for pyinstrument-0.13.1-py36_0.tar.bz2 - moving package to C:\Users\jvanzundert\conda-bld\broken
WARNING:conda_build.build:Tests failed for pyinstrument-0.13.1-py36_0.tar.bz2 - moving package to C:\Users\jvanzundert\conda-bld\broken
removing: pyinstrument-0.13.1-py36_0.tar.bz2
TESTS FAILED: pyinstrument-0.13.1-py36_0.tar.bz2
```

Is this a problem with my setup, or the tutorial?

For my own package, I think my layout should be such (note that I'm relatively new to Python)

```
- <package name>
    + <package name>
        + __init__.py (empty)
        + <package name>.py
    + meta.yaml
    + setup.py (only an empty print statement)
    + bld.bat
```

The contents of the meta.yaml file:

```
package:
  name: <package name>
  version: "0.0.1"

requirements:
  host:
    - python

  run:
    - python

test:
  imports:
    - <package name>

source:
  path: $RECIPE_DIR\..
```

But that does not work, also fails on the tests like the `pyinstrument` example.